# 2 transformers for 1 doorbell. How do I choose a new one

Tags: transformer, doorbell

As with another post I have older home, and someone wired 2 transformers for a doorbell in parallel.  After a panel change, bell doesn’t work.  Replies said that a single, proper transformer would be the smart solution.

The 1959 NuTone bell unit has no marks (that I can find) to know the required voltage.  Is there a way to figure it out?

Comment: If you are not married to the 59 NuTone , try one of the new wireless doorbells available almost everywhere.

Comment: When you say panel change, do you mean your main electrical panel?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Odds are you need a 16VAC transformer.

Comment: very likely that the panel replacement resulted in reversing polarity of one of the transformers, and they dead-shorted into each other until something burned out.   Having 2 transformers paralleled is foolish, they are likely to fight each other due to varying voltages from manufacturing tolerances.

Comment: 1.  Yes, a licensed electrician replaced the panel.  2. The doorbell no longer works.  I want to fix it.      Replies about reversed wires make sense.  Before doing anything, Voltage across each transformer read 6 V.  I haven’t tried isolating each, but when I disconnected one transformer, the other jumped to 12 V and the front doorbell worked!  Haven’t figured out how to restore the rear one, but reversing wires seems easy to try.

Answer (score 3):

Put a voltmeter set to AC volts on the output each of the two transformers, when their outputs are connected to nothing else, and their inputs are powered.

If it was working before someone changed it, likely the two are presently connected so they are opposite phase and cancelling each other. If they have not been fried, swapping two leads would restore it to the way it was.

Most old-fangled doorbells are not all that picky about voltage, so a middle-of-the-road common voltage like 16 VAC will likely work. But measuring what it had before is the best bet.